# TYPO3 tx_news routeEnhancer for searchSubject minimumDate and maximumDate

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-11.x

I've implemented the tx_news search form with search subject, minimum date and maximum date.

Now I need to define the corresponding route enhancer for speaking URLs.

Unfortunately, I can't find an example of this in the documentation, nor can I find one on the web.

The URL looks i.e. like this `https://mydomain.tld/news/?tx_news_pi1[search][subject]=Test&tx_news_pi1[search][minimumDate]=2023-02-01&tx_news_pi1[search][maximumDate]=2023-02-10`

I have tried the following configuration - but it does not work:

```
routeEnhancers:
    NewsPlugin:
        type: Extbase
        extension: News
        plugin: Pi1
        routes:
            - routePath: '/suche/{minimum_date}-{maximum_date}-{search_term}'
                _controller: 'News::list'
                _arguments:
                    search_term: search/subject
                    minimum_date: search/minimumDate
                    maximum_date: search/maximumDate
```

Environment

```
TYPO3 version: 11.5.24
news version: 10.0.3
Composer Mode: no
```

Comment: Your enhancer is pointing to `News::list` which does not have a `search`-parameter... IMO, you'd like to configure `_controller: 'News::searchResult'`

Answer (score 0):

And here is my working solution: https://github.com/georgringer/news/issues/2014